# "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported" After the replace of the motherboard

Tags: motherboard

I've newly replaced a motherboard to the below one(shown in the link).

And as I boot the computer I get the following messages with the shell environment.

**Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.**

I've already inserted the CD which came with the motherboard.

As now, BIOS window can be displayed.

The ssd and other components like USB have been recognized by the computer.

What should I do for next?

The below components are mine.

[CPU(i5 10th generation)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Generation-Corei5-10400F-BX8070110400F-Japanese-Distribution/dp/B086MHSTWN)

[Memory(4_GB)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WVSLBHG)

[motherboard](https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=1008)

[graphic card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AZ7W88O)

**What I tried after I've read the answer shown below.**

I located the place where the os has been installed.

But I've been struggling to locate where the GRUB has been installed.

I tried "ls (hdX, Y)/boot/grub"

and got

"error:unknown file system",

"error: `/boot/grub` not found"

"themes/ x86_64_efi/ locale/ fonts/ unicode.pf2 grubenv grub.cfg"←place where OS exists.

Comment: What operating system are you trying to install?  Also, you enter your EFI firmware settings (wrongly aka BIOS) WITHOUT a disk (USB/CD/DVD).. start there.

Comment: The CD that came with the motherboard has DRIVERS on it, not an operating system.  You need an operating system and that CD is WORTHLESS until you have one.. chances are the CD is only for Windows.  Also, I wouldn't install the manufacturers driver CD unless you end up needing it for some reason (you probably won').

Comment: You risk to have outdated drivers on the CD. Try to manage without it, and install drivers only for Windows/Linux devices that don't work well. However, your problem is apparently with Grub.

Comment: I'm back now. I will try the stuff(s).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I  'm trying to install  a linux-like operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two articles that describe solutions for the problem.

**Solution 1 : GRUB**

This comes from the article
[How to Fix Minimal BASH Like Line Editing is Supported GRUB Error In Linux?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/)

- Boot into Grub where the error is displayed
- Locate your Linux disk with the command `ls` which will display your
  disks and their file-system. Linux will usually use
  ext2/ext3/ext4
- When the partition is found, set `root` and `prefix` variables:

  - *root*: Variable which points where the entire Linux OS is installed.
  - *prefix*: Variable which points where the GRUB is installed.

using the command:

```
    grub> set root=(hdX, Y)
    grub> set prefix=(hdX, Y)/boot/grub
```

- Install the `normal` module and load it:

  ```
    insmod normal
    normal
  ```
- Now you should be able to boot into Linux
- Update GRUB with these commands in the terminal:

  ```
    sudo grub-install /dev/sdXY
    sudo update-grub
  ```

  where X is disk number and Y is partition number of the EFI partition.
  To find which partition it is, use Disks or GParted to check.
- Restart and it should work now.

**Solution 2 : Live Linux**

This comes from the article
[Fix Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB Error In Linux](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/).

- Boot in to the live Linux USB
- Mount the root partition and EFI partitions (use your disks):

  ```
    sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
  ```
- install grub for UEFI:

  ```
    sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=ubuntu  --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi
  ```
- Restart Linux:

  ```
    shutdown -r now
  ```
- Grub should be back to normal.

You will find more details in the links, including the steps for a
non-EFI computer.

Comment: How do I locate where GRUB has been installed?

Comment: You don't need to do that. When you have that message, you should automatically be booted into Grub. If not, then what exactly happens when you boot?

Comment: As I press the power button , I automatically be induced to the GRUB display.
So you mean , I don't need to do     " grub> set prefix=(hdX, Y)/boot/grub" right?

Comment: You need that for running `normal`, and you should be looking for your Linux partition, not EFI. I suggest reading carefully the linked article, it has screenshots that you can compare.

Comment: I see. By the way, the solution1 has worked! Thx!

Comment: NICE detailed answer mr. harrymc.  THATS how you do it!! ;)